# Adding 'active' class to wp_nav_menu when viewing post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site comprised mostly of pages, but there is one page (news section) that contains posts and categories like a blog would. I'm generating my nav using [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) with only the top-level pages displayed. I have styles set for the current link and the current link's parent that use the .current-menu-item and .current-page-ancestor classes that wp_nav_menu() automatically adds.

However, when you're viewing a post within the news section, no classes are added to the nav to indicate that you're in that section, and there's no way to style the "news" link to show that it's the section of the site the user is in.

Is there a way for WP to "know" that posts belong to that page? It's not a category because since no other sections of the site contain posts, the categories field is open and the editors can add whatever categories they want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your "News" page set as your blog page, in the "Reading" settings?  If so, it should add the class "current-menu-parent" and "current-post-parent" to the "News" `<li>` when you are viewing a post.

Comment: When I did that, News quit using news.php as its template and began using home.php, which was my template for the home page. I have no idea why this happened but it does that unless I set "Your latest posts" in "Reading Settings".

Comment: It will use `index.php` as the template.

Comment: If you don't want to switch the `index.php` template, you should be able to the target the News menu item using CSS.  The body of the page should have the class `.single` for the news entries, and each menu `li` will have a unique ID.  It would be something like: `.single #menu-item-58 { // CSS HERE }`.

Comment: I have an index.php template, which is a copy of news.php. The news section ignores that template and instead uses home.php, which is completely unrelated. I don't know what is causing this because it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: is the news page also your home page?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wordpress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) (and specifically [this diagram](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)) a single post is being displayed by a file called `single.php` (or `single-<post_type>.php`. A set of posts from a category will be displayed by `category-<post_type>.php` template file.

Now, if you abide to this hierarchy, you'll have two more templates - news list and news detail page. Having two pages with these templates will make them automatically listed by Wordpress menu-generating function.

If that's not enough for you, you should use `WP_Query` to manually list your pages. If you decide to do it this way, one or two if statements should do the job.

Comment: I have a single.php template. I don't need individual category templates as categories are being used solely for internal organization purposes. I have a bunch of static pages, each with their own template. One of those is news.php, which has a loop to go through the posts and display them. I want "news" to be highlighted on the nav when viewing a single post.

Comment: Can echo your nav using WP_Query? That's the easiest solution I can see.